# pass associative array as data to jquery ajax function

Tags: jquery

I would like to call a jquery ajax function and pass in data.  I know the data is supposed to be formatted into a query string.  If I pass in something like `$(':checked')` as the data then it will be formatted as `tagname=value1&tagname=value2...etc` which is good.

Now, I want to replace the jquery result with an associative array that has some integers in it i get `value1=true$value2=true`. That is not what I want.

How can I format the associative array with a key to pass into jquery ajax calls?

Comment: Where will this associative array come from? Manual made or JQuery output? If is JQuery output, replacing $ for & will do the work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've got one solution that I figured out.  I created the following function which returns an array that can be passed in as data to jquery ajax function:

```
function () {
    var kvArray = [];
    for (x in MyAssociativeArray) {
        var kv = {};
        kv.name = "NameIWantToAssign";
        kv.value = x;
        kvArray.push(kv);
    }

    return kvArray;
};
```

The trick is to use the .name and .value properties.  I got the idea after reading the following jquery documentation:

*If the object passed is in an Array, it must be an array of objects in the format returned by .serializeArray()*

```
[{name:"first",value:"Rick"},
{name:"last",value:"Astley"},
{name:"job",value:"Rock Star"}]
```

There's probably a better way though. Please comment or provide another answer if you know.